# Size of a tcp packet on BSD

Tags: unix, tcp, freebsd

If i need to find out the size of a tcp packet on BSD.....what do we need to do?

Is there some utility which allows for this?

Comment: Please be more specific. Size of the packet on the wire? How much memory it takes up? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean the max possible size? if so, google for [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) (Maximum Transmission Unit)

Comment: no i am looking for the current size of a package sent via tcp. how can i get the size of this on the web server?

Comment: Then you may use a sniffer, as suggested in Vasil's answer. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Try ethereal.

Comment: Now Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/).  But yes, it's an excellent interface for tcpdump and related utilities.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `tcpdump` would be the easiest solution.